# How to display certain image for different gender

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Simple script i am sure, but can't seem to find an article on it. If there is one ,i do appolagize.

What i am trying to achieve is simple.

> If `$user_gender = male` then display male symbol image
>
> If `$user_gender = female` then display female symbol image

I just can't figure out how to put it into coding. I am not a `PHP` kind of guy.

using `php sdk 3.1.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it...  But there are many other ways it could be done!

```
if ($user_gender == "male") {
    echo '<img src="/maleimage.png" />';
}
else if ($user_gender == "female") {
    echo '<img src="/femaleimage.png" />';
}
else {
    echo '<img src="/genderneutralimage.png" />';
}
```

Comment: having trouble testing it due to my session not carrying over to the page im trying to acheieve this on, will post and accept once i can test. BTW know a good way to test if the session is being carried over?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question - [get application user's info - Facebook-GRAPH API-PHP SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623806/get-application-users-info-facebook-graph-api-php-sdk) and take a look here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.getInfo/

If you can provide the exact code of where you're at, we can help more. Until then all we can be is general.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a conditional statement over there to find out the gender,

```
if($user_gender == "male")
{
$image = "/images/male.jpg";
}
else if($user_gender == "female")
{
$image = "/images/female.jpg";
}
else
{
// For default image display
$image = "/images/default.jpg";
}
```